# Babel plugin not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs

Babel is giving me this error `Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-svg-sprite-loader '`

This is my `babel` file.

```
    {
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": false }],
    "inline-react-svg",
    "inline-import-data-uri",
    "svg-sprite-loader "
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions why I'm getting this error? I've already installed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space in the name `svg-sprite-loader`